# How to debug CoffeeScript using the generated source maps?

Tags: coffeescript, source-maps

How to debug CoffeeScript using the generated source maps?  Do I need to include the map file?  What else do I need to do?  I'm currently including both the compiled JS file and the map file, but my Firefox debugger doesn't seem to be doing anything special....

Answer (score 2):

SourceMap debugging is only available on the next Firefox release, starting from Firefox 23.

You can download the developper preview (google for firefox 23). It should be available as RC during august according to Mozilla website.

In practice, you don't have to include the map file in your html file, you just have to reference your map in the javascript file. But the CoffeeScript compiler does it for you.

If you want to give a try at debugging CoffeeScript with SourceMap, you can try with Google Chrome dev Tools. Be sure to check `Enable source maps` in the dev tool configuration.

If you need further advices or examples on how to debugg CoffeeScript with Chrome, ask and I'll edit this post.

Comment: For completeness: You can also consume sourcemaps in JS with the Moz's Source Maps library. https://github.com/mozilla/source-map/